# The forward slash (English vs Japanese)

Tags: orthography, punctuation

In English it's common to list multiple items as item/item/item, with the / representing **or**.

What about in Japanese?  Do I keep the forward slash, or maybe 「・」 so it would be アイテム・アイテム・アイテム?

Context: the list will be in a GUI, probably a drop down list item with no other verbiage around it.

Comment: I think it is usual to use アイテムやアイテムやアイテム等 for item, item, or item, etc. If you really want to use punctuation, ・ is better than slash, I think. Maybe tell us a bit more about in what context you plan to use your list of multiple items.

Comment: @user1205935 - No reason you should know the context, but as with most of my recent questions the list will be in a GUI, probably a drop down list item with no other verbiage around it.

Comment: @Peter: On the contrary, context is the only way to know which question you're asking. Without context, the question is unanswerable since there simply isn't enough detail. The choice for a sentence, a list on a GUI checkbox, and a list on a sign have completely different answers.

Comment: @jkerian - What I wrote came out wrong (I see that now).  I didn't mean there was no reason for him to know the context, but that there was no reason why he would already have known it. You are of course absolutely right that context is crucial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slash is not among the symbols traditionally used in punctuation in Japanese, and *nakaguro* “・” is the symbol for this purpose.  However, the forward slash is also common nowadays, especially when user interface of application software is concerned.